# pattern substitution of file name

Tags: bash, shell, sed, rename

I have to create again my question, since all of the found sollution did not work for my case.
Dealing with many filles I would like to use some one line utility, which allows to make several substitution in the name of the files. This is format of the name of input files

```
1300_grid12_04_lig_cne_767_lig.dlg
```

This is expected output:

```
130004_lig_cne_767.dlg
```

So for each of the file I have to substitute two patterns "*grid12*" to "_" and "_lig." to "."
Manually for the ensemble of the filles I can achive it using two subsequent loops, which is very slow method dealing with huge number of filles.

```
# 1st loop over the files and substitute patter _grid12_ to _.
for file in ./*.dlg; do mv -v "$file" "${file/_grid12_/_}"; done
# 2nd loop these filles to substitute _lig. to .
for file in ./*.dlg; do mv -v "$file" "${file/_lig./.}"; done
```

I've already tried rename command, which did not recognize properly the patters:

```
rename 's/_grid12_/_/g' *.dlg
```

Is it possible to avoid looping over the filles to do it in a rapid way?

Comment: There are several utilities that go by the name `rename` - can you identify which one you have (via `rename --version` for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should speed up the loop twice as it renames each file directly to the final name.

```
for file in ./*.dlg; do
    new=${file/_grid12_/_}
    mv -v "$file" "${new/_lig./.}"
done
```

You can probably get some acceleration from running the renames in parallel (but the IO might become the bottleneck easily):

```
cpu_tally=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
for file in ./*.dlg; do
    new=${file/_grid12_/_}
    printf '%s\0' "$file" "${new/_lig./.}"
done  | xargs -r0 -n2 -P$cpu_tally -exec mv -v
```

Comment: and is it possible to write it in one line syntax as I demonstrated in my first topic ? :)

Comment: Yes, just replace newlines by semicolons.

Comment: is it correct ?  for file in ./*.dlg; do new=${file/_grid12_/_}; mv -v "$file" "${new/_lig./.}"; done

Comment: @user3470313: Yes. But check the update, too.

Comment: With `-P0`, it will start as many `mv` processes as there are files to rename in parallel. That's bound to be counter-productive. You may want to limit that to little more than the number of available CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

What's slow is executing the standalone `mv` utility for each file. You could switch to `zsh` where the `mv` utility can be made builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/files # makes mv and a few other file manipulation utilities builtin
autoload -Uz zmv   # batch renaming tool
zmv -v '*.dlg' '${${f/_grid12_/_}/_lig./.}'
```

`zmv` has extra features over a simple loop. For instance, it will abort before starting the renaming if it finds conflicts.

The simple loop could be:

```
for f (*.dlg(#qoN)) mv -vi -- ${${f/_grid12_/_}/_lig./.}
```

Here also adding a `(#qoN)` glob qualifier to disable the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
touch 1300_grid12_04_lig_cne_767_lig.dlg
# if you have few
parallel mv {} '{= s/_grid12_04//; s/_lig.dlg/.dlg/ =}' ::: *.dlg
# if you have thousands
printf "%s\0" *.dlg |
  parallel -0 mv {} '{= s/_grid12_04//; s/_lig.dlg/.dlg/ =}'
ls 1300*dlg
```